# Visual Studio 2013 Installer Hang

Tags: visual-studio

Problem: 
The installer is stuck at "Configuring Your System...this may take a while" every time I try to install. I've tried the regular (full) install, the web installer, deleting temp, deleting packagecache. Nothing works. I have also tried installing with UAC off but that does nothing

Screenshot:

[image: Hang]

Log Files:

```
[0CD4:0CD8][2014-09-18T20:29:27]i323: Registering package dependency provider: {FD51D6A8-D687-463D-85AE-BBF1B650CD99}, version: 12.0.21005, package: professional_finalizer
[0D08:0D0C][2014-09-18T20:29:27]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: professional_finalizer
[0CD4:0CD8][2014-09-18T20:29:27]i301: Applying execute package: professional_finalizer, action: Repair, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{FD51D6A8-D687-463D-85AE-BBF1B650CD99}v12.0.21005\packages\professional_finalizer.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1" SKIP_APPID_SETUP=""'
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:31]i000: MUX:  Go to CancelPrompt page.
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:31]i000: MUX:  Go to Progress page.
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:39]i000: MUX:  Go to CancelPrompt page.
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:39]i000: MUX:  Metrics: ShouldSendData=False
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:39]i000: MUX:  Permission to upload: No
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:39]i000: MUX:  Preparing to serialize data.
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:39]i000: MUX:  Data serialized.
[0D08:0F8C][2014-09-18T21:10:39]i000: MUX:  Number of SQM File queued: 2
```

THEN NOTHING, at posting time it is 21:35 where I am...

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

**I've figured out a workaround.**

First I noticed that the issue is with the "package-finalizer"

```
Registering package dependency provider: {FD51D6A8-D687-463D-85AE-BBF1B650CD99}, version: 12.0.21005, package: professional_finalizer
```

So i extracted it from the iso and ran it using msiexec

```
msiexec /i professional_finalizer.msi /lv "log.log"
```

in the log file was this

```
09/18/14 21:46:22 DDSet_Status: Launching "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup /AllowDuringSetup /log "C:\Users\~~~~~\AppData\Local\Temp\VS1.tmp"
09/18/14 21:46:22 DDSet_Entry: Starting process, will wait for up to 60 minutes to complete...
```

And so I ran 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /setup

And Bingo, It works